# C If statements not working

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

Noob here trying to run some basic code.  I have some if statements that are not operating when I try to run them together, but when I isolate the last if statement by commenting out the others, it works (the comments are in there for you to see how I did that).    Can anyone explain why the if statements don't work together (I have tried else if and it still did not work)?  **Here you must pick the numbers 1, 2, and 3 for x, y, and z respectively**, and the output should assign aaa, bbb, or ccc to 1 at random.  My apologies if the code is ugly.  THANKS!

```
    int x, y, z, a, b, c, d, e, aaa, bbb, ccc, r;

    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    c = 0;
    aaa = 0;
    bbb = 0;
    ccc = 0;

    printf("Pick x:\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);

    printf("Pick y:\n");
    scanf("%d",&y);

    printf("Pick z:\n");
    scanf("%d",&z); 

    printf("You chose %d, %d, %d.\n",x,y,z);

if (x == 1 || y == 1 || z == 1) {a = (1);}

    printf("a = %d\n", a);

if (x == 2 || y == 2 || z == 2) {b = (1);}

    printf("b = %d\n", b);

if (x == 3 || y == 3 || z == 3) {c = (1);}

    printf("c = %d\n", c);

    if (a == 1 && b == 1 && c == 1 && d != 1 && e != 1) {
        /*if (aaa < bbb && aaa < ccc) {aaa = (aaa + 1);}
        if (bbb < aaa && bbb < ccc) {bbb = (bbb + 1);}
        if (ccc < bbb && ccc < aaa) {ccc = (ccc + 1);}
        if (aaa == bbb && aaa != ccc){int r = rand() % 2 + 1;
            printf("aRANDOM2 = %d\n",r);
            if (r == 1) {aaa = (aaa + 1);}
            if (r == 2) {bbb = (bbb + 1);}
        if (aaa == ccc && aaa != bbb){int r = rand() % 2 + 1;
            printf("bRANDOM2 = %d\n",r);
            if (r == 1) {aaa = (aaa + 1);}
            if (r == 2) {ccc = (ccc + 1);}
        if (ccc == bbb && aaa != ccc){int r = rand() % 2 + 1;
            printf("cRANDOM2 = %d\n",r);
            if (r == 1) {ccc = (ccc + 1);}
            if (r == 2) {bbb = (bbb + 1);}*/
        if (aaa == bbb && bbb == ccc){int r = rand() % 3 + 1;
            printf("RANDOM3 = %d\n",r);
            if (r == 1) {aaa = (aaa + 1);}
            if (r == 2) {bbb = (bbb + 1);}
            if (r == 3) {ccc = (ccc + 1);}
}}/*}}}*/


    printf("aaa = %d\n", aaa);
    printf("bbb = %d\n", bbb);
    printf("ccc = %d\n", ccc);

return 0;
```

Comment: where are your main function and header declarations ??
you better fully post the code.

Comment: The short answer here is that you've written illegible code that you can no longer read. A few things to consider: (1) Use more, smaller, well-named functions (2) Use meaningful variable names (3) Make if statements that read like english. A large part of learning to program well is to learn to manage complexity (i.e. simplify). It's hard to get much done if you can't read your own handwriting.

Comment: Your code isn't really up to scratch. But I can tell you that the is statements work. You just coded them wrong. Hard to know what you should have written.

Comment: Run your code through a formatter like astyle or manually set all the indenting to something rational and view it in an editor with  syntax highlighting. You will probably spot the problem.

Comment: Please be more specific what you mean by "not working". Which `if` statement are you referring to? What are you expecting to happen? What are you getting instead?

Comment: `d` and `e` are used, but never initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to the commenting, each of the last three aaa/bbb/ccc if statements was nested within the previous such if statement.  Thus, when `if (aaa == bbb && aaa != ccc)` tested as false, all the rest of the code up to the line of close braces was skipped.

In other words, what it really did was this:

```
    if (aaa == bbb && aaa != ccc) {
        int r = rand() % 2 + 1;
        printf("aRANDOM2 = %d\n",r);
        if (r == 1) {aaa = (aaa + 1);}
        if (r == 2) {bbb = (bbb + 1);}
            if (aaa == ccc && aaa != bbb) {
            int r = rand() % 2 + 1;
            printf("bRANDOM2 = %d\n",r);
            if (r == 1) {aaa = (aaa + 1);}
            if (r == 2) {ccc = (ccc + 1);}
            if (ccc == bbb && aaa != ccc) {
                int r = rand() % 2 + 1;
                printf("cRANDOM2 = %d\n",r);
                if (r == 1) {ccc = (ccc + 1);}
                if (r == 2) {bbb = (bbb + 1);}
                if (aaa == bbb && bbb == ccc) {
                    int r = rand() % 3 + 1;
                    printf("RANDOM3 = %d\n",r);
                    if (r == 1) {aaa = (aaa + 1);}
                    if (r == 2) {bbb = (bbb + 1);}
                    if (r == 3) {ccc = (ccc + 1);}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Probably what you want to do is to move three of the close braces to the end of their respective blocks, like this:

```
    if (aaa == bbb && aaa != ccc) {
        int r = rand() % 2 + 1;
        printf("aRANDOM2 = %d\n",r);
        if (r == 1) {aaa = (aaa + 1);}
        if (r == 2) {bbb = (bbb + 1);}
    }
    if (aaa == ccc && aaa != bbb) {
        int r = rand() % 2 + 1;
        printf("bRANDOM2 = %d\n",r);
        if (r == 1) {aaa = (aaa + 1);}
        if (r == 2) {ccc = (ccc + 1);}
    }
    if (ccc == bbb && aaa != ccc) {
        int r = rand() % 2 + 1;
        printf("cRANDOM2 = %d\n",r);
        if (r == 1) {ccc = (ccc + 1);}
        if (r == 2) {bbb = (bbb + 1);}
    }
    if (aaa == bbb && bbb == ccc) {
        int r = rand() % 3 + 1;
        printf("RANDOM3 = %d\n",r);
        if (r == 1) {aaa = (aaa + 1);}
        if (r == 2) {bbb = (bbb + 1);}
        if (r == 3) {ccc = (ccc + 1);}
    }
}
```

Comment: Along with the fact that aaa, bbb and ccc aren't updated before the ifs.

Comment: Thanks for mucking through that.  That did the trick.

Comment: Wow!  Now i am discovering that when things evaluate as true, later if statements may evaluate as true that were initially false.  Very Interesting!  Using else if () solves this problem.

Comment: Because some of the variables they are evaluating are changed in the bodies of the earlier if statements, yes.  If you don't want that to happen, you could use "else if" instead of "if" for the last three major if blocks.